# How to get whole contentState in draftjs

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

How to get the whole contentState in draftjs?

For example, I want to modify the content font size by clicking on a button. The default is all contentState. The user did not need to click CMD+A in mac.

Forgive for my poor English.Thank U.

Answer (score 3):

When you click `cmd+A` you set selection on whole content. You can do it programmatically with draft.js [`SelectionState`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-selection-state.html) after a click on the button. Look at this working example in action - https://jsfiddle.net/k7wghwuj/1/

Some explanations. Before you should specify styles, which you will apply. For example, create two styles: the first - red background, and the second - large font size (26px). Define customStyleMap object. Keys of this object should be unique names of your custom styles and values - objects with appropriate styles.

```
const customStyleMap = {
  redBackground: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  largeText: {
    fontSize: 26
  },
};
```

Pass this object to `customStyleMap` property of Editor component:

```
<Editor
  placeholder="Type away :)"
  editorState={this.state.editorState}
  onChange={this._handleChange}
  customStyleMap={customStyleMap}
/>
```

Add `onClick` handler-functions. Pass name of appropriate style as the first argument.

```
<button onClick={() => this.applyStyleOnWholeContent('redBackground')}>
  set red background for whole content
</button>
<button onClick={() => this.applyStyleOnWholeContent('largeText')}>
  set large font size for whole content
</button>
```

Inside `applyStyleOnWholeContent` you should get the first and the last `ContentBlock` and programmatically set selection with `new SelectionState` constructor.

```
applyStyleOnWholeContent = (styleName) => {
  const editorState = this.state.editorState;
  let currentContent = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent();
  const firstBlock = currentContent.getBlockMap().first();
  const lastBlock = currentContent.getBlockMap().last();
  const firstBlockKey = firstBlock.getKey();
  const lastBlockKey = lastBlock.getKey();
  const lengthOfLastBlock = lastBlock.getLength();

  let newSelection = new SelectionState({
    anchorKey: firstBlockKey,
    anchorOffset: 0,
    focusKey: lastBlockKey,
    focusOffset: lengthOfLastBlock
  });
  ...
```

After that, with [`Modifier.applyInlineStyle`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-modifier.html#applyinlinestyle) you should generate new 
content state, update `EditorState`, reset selection and apply your changes.

```
  ...
  currentContent = Modifier.applyInlineStyle(
    currentContent,
    newSelection,
    styleName,
  )

  let newEditorState = EditorState.push(
    editorState,
    currentContent,
  )

  newSelection = new SelectionState({
    anchorKey: 0,
    anchorOffset: 0,
    focusKey: 0,
    focusOffset: 0
  });

  newEditorState = EditorState.forceSelection(newEditorState, newSelection);

  this._handleChange(newEditorState);
}
```